# What is the time complexity of this algorithm which retrieves values from a 2D array?

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

This is the algorithm to retrieve values from a `2D array`, what will be the `time complexity` of this algorithm?

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
 for(j=0;j<2;j++){
    x = arr[i][j]
  }
}
```

So the `time complexity` of this algorithm would be `O(2n)` or `O(n^2)`? What is the `reason`?

Comment: O(2n) Reason: The inner loop iterates 2 times

Comment: Note that `O(2n) = O(n)` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outer loop is iterating n times, but inner loop is iterating only two times, So time complexity will be O(2n) and not O(n^2). And

```
O(2n) = O(n)
```